# Processing: How can I find the number of times two fields are equal in a CSV file?

Tags: processing

I'm learning Processing for the first time and I've been tasked to deal with data but it's been terribly confusing for me.

For every line of a CSV file (apart from the header), I want to compare two specific columns of each. i.e. ListA vs ListB

For example, with the data below:

**ListA,ListB**

Male,Yes

Male,No

Female,Yes

Male,Yes

And for example, I want to check for all instances that a value in ListA is "Male" AND that the corresponding value in ListB is "Yes". In this scenario, I should get the value "2" for the two rows this is true.

How would I do that?

For now, I have a 2D String array of the data in the CSV file. From that I managed to assign specific columns as ListA and ListB. I tried using sort but it would only sort one list and not both at the same time.

Current relevant code:

```
for (int i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
 listA[i-1] = csv[i][int(whichA)];
 listB[i-1] = csv[i][int(whichB)];
}

lA = Arrays.asList(listA);
lB = Arrays.asList(listB);
```

Not sure if this code really helps makes things clearer though. :/

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Need to see your current code, at least the relevant portions, so that we can help you.

Comment: Added relevant code, but not sure if it helps makes things clearer

Comment: Yes, the code always helps:)

Comment: Are you just counting the number of rows that meet your conditions or do you need the data in them?

Comment: I need the data in them. I'm using Collections.frequency for another purpose, or is there a way of using this to retain the data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this should do what you need it to. Pseudocode:

```
int numRows = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (array1[i] equals "Male" AND array2[i] equals "Yes") {
       ++numRows;
      //add to new collection here if you need the data 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to do that. Thanks a bunch. If I want to check for different ListB values (i.e. count Yes's and No's), would doing an integer array work? Currently I have this code but it's not working. 
`if (listD[i].equals(chosenD) && listB[i].equals(orderB[j])) {
        
counterB[j]++;
}` Sorry I can't seem to format the answer into individual lines of code.

Comment: That's going to give you an array full of 1's and 0's.  If the two choices are limited to Y/N, then you already know the total and only need one of the answers to find the other count. So you can just increment a simple `int yesCounter` if that's what you need.